# How to rename index which is another tablespace oracle?

Tags: oracle, indexing

I want to rename an index which is in another tablespace.

Is the following SQL (oracle) valid?

```
ALTER INDEX OLD_INDEX_NAME RENAME TO NEW_INDEX_NAME TABLESPACE OTHER_TABLE_SPACE;
```

Comment: why not try it yourself?

Comment: I don't have admin rights to create the tablespace and I don't have access to the environment where the tablespace is created. I have to create an update script which will be executed there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tablespace doesn't matter; you aren't *relocating* index, just *renaming* it.

Sample table in one tablespace:

```
SQL> create table test (id number) tablespace user_rw;

Table created.

SQL> select table_name, tablespace_name from user_tables where table_name = 'TEST';

TABLE_NAME      TABLESPACE_NAME
--------------- --------------------
TEST            USER_RW
```

Index on that table, in another tablespace:

```
SQL> create index i1test on test (id) tablespace rwmig;

Index created.

SQL> select index_name, table_name, tablespace_name
  2  from user_indexes where index_name = 'I1TEST';

INDEX_NAME      TABLE_NAME      TABLESPACE_NAME
--------------- --------------- --------------------
I1TEST          TEST            RWMIG
```

Rename index:

```
SQL> alter index i1test rename to i1test_new;

Index altered.
```

Result: index is renamed, tablespace remained the same (why wouldn't it?):

```
SQL> select index_name, table_name, tablespace_name
  2  from user_indexes where index_name = 'I1TEST_NEW';

INDEX_NAME      TABLE_NAME      TABLESPACE_NAME
--------------- --------------- --------------------
I1TEST_NEW      TEST            RWMIG

SQL>
```